# JavaScript Event Delegation not working. I want to toggle multiple elements. How I can do it?

Tags: javascript, events, onclick

I am confused, I want to create toggle in multiple elements but my CSS class name will be the same. I try a lot of ways like `foreach` and `for of` loop but my code is not working. How can I solve it?

The main problem is when I use

> `if (t.className === 'click'){content.classList.toggle('toggle')}`

my first button works properly but when I click my second button my first button is toggling but the second button is doing nothing

Here is my code:

```js
let rootDev = document.querySelector('.rootdiv');
let btnClick = document.querySelector('.click');
let content = document.querySelector('.content');

rootDev.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let t = e.target

  if (t.className === 'click') {
    content.classList.add('toggle')
  } else {
    content.classList.remove('toggle')
  }
})
```

```css
.card {
  width: 25%;
  background: rgb(158, 158, 158);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.toggle {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="rootdiv">
  <div class="card">
    <button class="click">Click</button>
    <div class="content">
      I am a event method somebody click me!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <button class="click">Click</button>
    <div class="content">
      I am a event method somebody click me!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of querying all the elements upfront you can just use [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling) to get the associated `content` div.

As for toggling the class you can use [toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) which combines `add` and `remove`.

```js
let rootDev = document.querySelector('.rootdiv');

rootDev.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let t = e.target

  if (t.className === 'click') {
    t.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('toggle');
  }
})
```

```css
.card {
  width: 25%;
  background: rgb(158, 158, 158);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.toggle {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="rootdiv">
  <div class="card">
    <button class="click">Click</button>
    <div class="content">
      I am a event method somebody click me!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <button class="click">Click</button>
    <div class="content">
      I am a event method somebody click me!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Using [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).** Makes selecting an element within a common container easily.

```js
let rootDev = document.querySelector('.rootdiv');

rootDev.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let t = e.target

  if (t.className === 'click') {
    // parentElement in this case is '.card'
    const content = t.parentElement.querySelector('.content');
    content.classList.toggle('toggle');
  }
})
```

```css
.card {
  width: 25%;
  background: rgb(158, 158, 158);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.toggle {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="rootdiv">
  <div class="card">
    <button class="click">Click</button>
    <p>I'm in the way</p>
    <div class="content">
      I am a event method somebody click me!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <button class="click">Click</button>
    <p>I'm in the way</p>
    <div class="content">
      I am a event method somebody click me!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Using a [data-*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) reference.** This allows you to easily select an element from anywhere on the page.

```js
let rootDev = document.querySelector('.rootdiv');

rootDev.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let t = e.target

  if (t.className === 'click') {
    const id = t.dataset.id;
    const content = document.getElementById(id);
    content.classList.toggle('toggle');
  }
})
```

```css
.card {
  width: 25%;
  background: rgb(158, 158, 158);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.toggle {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="rootdiv">
  <div class="card">
    <button class="click" data-id="content-1">Click</button>
    <p>I'm in the way</p>
    <div id="content-1" class="content">
      I am a event method somebody click me!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <button class="click" data-id="content-2">Click</button>
    <p>I'm in the way</p>
    <div id="content-2" class="content">
      I am a event method somebody click me!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, it works like magic. Give one more piece of information if I have more buttons like this, how will my page perform? Means will there be any performance issues on my page?

Comment: Think like my content div won't be always in the same position as it would my under three div or up three div. So how do I solve this?

Comment: @OmorFaruk I've added some extra (closed) snippets of common ways to solve your issue. You can of course also chain the [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling) (or [previousElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/previousElementSibling)) if you want to. As for performance issues it shouldn't be a problem, these are common and fast operations. You might even save some memory since you're only having a single event listener instead of multiple.

Comment: There are also a lot of [other properties / methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) to find an element. Too many to list them all.

Comment: Your last two example I am clear but Is there any other example?

Comment: please help me how can I remove toggle when I clike my another button?